# How to see AWS data-transfer inner region usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've created 2 accounts, one with S3 bucket and the other with EC2 instance which reads the bucket's data.
Both the EC2 and the S3 bucket are in the same region and I've enabled the [Requester Pays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html) for both the bucket the `getObject` request. (I know the inner-region data transfer is free anyway)

The funny thing is, I can't see these `data transfer` operations anywhere.
I've tried using 'Cost Explorer' (even with [this filter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-aws-cost-explorer-to-analyze-data-transfer-costs/) on) on both accounts but the inner-region data transfer is just not there.

Am I missing something? is inner-region data transfer not registered anywhere because it's free?

Comment: You are saying *inner-region* but I believe you mean *intra-region* -- data transfer within the same region.  Transfer between two regions is *inter-region* or *cross-region*.  With that in mind (*inter* = across boundaries, not what you want) you might re-check whether you are using the correct filter settings.